# Can these queries and "vLookups" be automated

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1POJdx-1VTqqWJ9S2Pbf2zmvTCqGF_yvKvnXtxwnEXKM/edit?usp=sharing   - Link to my reference sheets here:

I'm not familiar with the script and automation process of this end of the spectrum, but I figured I'd ask first. In my worksheet, we have 3 sheets of data reference, and within the sheet "All Possible Overstocks", from columns F-M, is where the formulas occur.

My question is, the 5 formulas that are present in F2, G2, H2, J2, and L2, could these live in one string of script that would output the same result? Essentially when this data is populated on a large scale, Google Sheets slows down to almost unusable with how much data is trying to be processed at once, so I'm hoping having one source of data would help eliminate that.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas or feedback, and thank you!

Comment: Hi. Please take a moment to consult [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The first sheet in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1POJdx-1VTqqWJ9S2Pbf2zmvTCqGF_yvKvnXtxwnEXKM/edit?usp=sharing) has about 40,000 blank rows at the bottom. Delete those blank rows to improve performance. See [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).

Your current fill-down formulas look like this:

`=VLOOKUP('True Complete'!H:H,A:B,2,false)`

To convert that to an array formula, use this pattern in row `2` of a free column:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup('True Complete'!H2:H, A2:B, columns(A2:B) ,false) ) )`